# NET USE command to connect to a shared folder on local LAN

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, scripting

I am trying to write a batch file to connect to a shared folder on my LAN.

The command reads:

```
net use s: \\<server add>\sharename /user:username
```

How do I include the password in the command as well?

I've tried:

`net use s: \\<server add>\sharename /user:username password`

and get an incorrect syntax error.

```
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

This is all SOHO so assume no Server on network.  I am using a windows 7 client.

Comment: You syntax is correct then I suppose there is an error on what you're passing to that command (a space? something...). Please provide real command (of course without real password...)

Comment: `net use s: \\192.168.1.x\share /user:user password`

Comment: it looks correct to me too

Comment: Hm, not working just bombs out with syntax error

Comment: It looks correct to me too

Comment: `net use s: \\<server add>\sharename /user:username (works)`

Comment: `net use s: \\<server add>\sharename /user:username password` (doesnt work)

Comment: could it be you have some `net` bat or command in the path before the real `net` in `windows\system32` ?

Comment: Sorry i'm not with you can you elaborate?

Comment: I dont understand the instruction?

Comment: does the password contains special symbols like `&|<>` ?

Comment: where net >> C:Windows\System32\net.exe

Comment: I've tried 2 separate clients now same result.

Comment: Try echo password | net usr

Comment: Try this syntax: `net use s: \\192.168.1.1\Share Password /USER:DomainOrHost\User`

Comment: @ Marged: I get a "the syntax of this command is:" message

Comment: @ Vojtech I get the same syntax error when trying that command.

Comment: Could you specify exact error message you get?

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior no matter how I try. It should allways show more specific error message.

Comment: Thats weird because its doing this on multiple clients..

Comment: I deleted the folder, recreated it and changed the name and it works now.. not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

The error message syntax positions the password (or a *) *before* the /USER: option.  Putting the password before the user has always seemed illogical to me, but it's always worked.